# Hint wanted: Any order-preserving $\phi:[m] \to [n]$ can be decomposed uniquely as composition of an injective and a surjective function

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplex

Let $[n]=\{0,1,...,n\}$. I would like to show that that Any order-preserving (meaning if $i \leq j$, then $\phi(i) \leq \phi(j))$ $\phi:[m] \to [n]$ can be decomposed uniquely as composition of an injective and a surjective function, i.e. $\phi=\phi_1\phi_2$, where $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are order-preserving and $\phi_1:[k] \to [n]$ is injective, $\phi_2:[m] \to [k]$ is surjective (for some $k$). I have shown that this decomposition exists, but I have hard time showing that this decomposition is unique. Can anyone give me some hint? Thank you.

Comment: I'd say, look at your proof/construction of existence, then try to construct another one and observe where it fails.

Comment: If $m=n$, this is not true. I mean in this case if $\phi_1$ is order-preserving (i.e. increasing) and injective, it has to be the identity. Same for $\phi_2$. So $\phi = id$, which is not true for $\phi\equiv 0$, which is order-preserving.

Comment: @amsmath Mmm...your argument is reasonable. Actually this is a problem coming from a course in MIT. (Q.1(c) in the link) Link: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-905-algebraic-topology-i-fall-2016/assignments/MIT18_905F16_pset1.pdf

Comment: Things change if you say that $\phi$ is order preserving if $i < j\,\Rightarrow\,\phi(i) < \phi(j)$. But that would mean already that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: @amsmath The map $\phi\equiv 0$ can be factored as a surjection $[m]\to \{0\}$ composed with an injection $\{0\}\to [n]$. Whether $m=n$ or not is immaterial.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that $\phi_2\colon [m]\to S$ and $\phi_1\colon S\to [n]$ for a linearly ordered set $S$ (which is unique up to isomorphism). Even if $m=n$, the maps $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ do not necesssarily go from $[m]\to[m]$.

Comment: @TashiWalde So, the exercise is not well posed. They should have written: show that there exists $k$, a op surjection $\phi_2 : [m]\to[k]$ and an op injection $\phi_1 : [k]\to[n]$ such that $\phi = \phi_1\circ\phi_2$. BTW, why have you deleted your question? Bad behaviour in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi:[m]\rightarrow[n]$ be an order-preserving map. Write $\phi([m])=\{x_0<x_1<\ldots <x_k\}$; i.e. the elements $x_i\in [n]$ are the image of $\phi$, such that $x_i<x_j$ if $i<j$. Then there is a injective order-preserving map $\phi_1:[k]\rightarrow[n]$ given by $\phi(i)=x_i$, and a surjective map $\phi_2:[m]\rightarrow[k]$ defined by $\phi(i)=x_{\phi_2(i)}$. By construction, $\phi_1\circ \phi_2(i)=x_{\phi_2(i)}=\phi(i)$.

On the other hand, suppose that there is some other factorization $\phi=\phi_1'\circ\phi_2'$ such that $\phi_1':[m]\rightarrow[k']$ and $\phi_2':[k']\rightarrow[n]$ are order-preserving, $\phi_1'$ is injective and $\phi_2'$ is surjective. Then note that $k'+1=|\phi_1'([k'])|=|\phi([m])|=k+1$, so $k'=k$.

To prove $\phi_1=\phi_1'$ and $\phi_2=\phi_2'$, it suffices to consider the co-domain restricted maps $\phi:[m]\rightarrow \phi([m])$, $\phi_1,\phi_1':[k]\rightarrow \phi([m])$. In this context, $\phi_1,\phi_1'$ are injective and surjective, hence bijective. Furthermore, note that an bijective order-preserving map has an order-preserving inverse.

Then $\phi_1^{-1}\circ\phi_1':[k]\rightarrow[k]$ is an order-preserving bijection; this is only possible if $\phi_1^{-1}\circ\phi_1'=1_{[k]}$, hence $\phi_1=\phi_1'$. But then, $\phi_2=\phi_1^{-1}\circ \phi_1\circ\phi_2=\phi_1^{-1}\circ\phi_2=\phi_2'$